# Group by and Sum for the list is the final aggregate result

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, linq, arraylist

Table data is:

```
Info
-----------------------------------------------
num    name   age    expenseN    cost    group
1      a      20
2      b      21 

InfoDetail
-----------------------------------------------
num    expenseN    cost       group
1      001         10.00      x
2      001         20.00      x
3      002         20.00      x
4      003         30.00      y
```

This is code:

```
public class _infoRepository
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int age { get; set; }
    public string expenseN { get; set; }
    public decimal cost { get; set; }
    public string group { get; set; }
}
public class _infoDetailRepository
{
    public string expenseN { get; set; }
    public decimal cost { get; set; }
    public string group { get; set; }
}


List<Info> result = new List<Info>();
var listInfoDetail = _infoDetailRepository.Query(p => p.group == "x").ToList();
var info1 = _infoRepository.Query(p => p.name = "a").FirstOrDefault();
for (int i = 0; i < listInfoDetail.Count; i++)
{
    result.Add(new Info()
    {
        name = info1.name,
        age = info1.age,
        expenseN = listInfoDetail[i].expenseN,
        cost = listInfoDetail[i].cost,
        group = listInfoDetail[i].group
    });
}
var info2 = _infoRepository.Query(p => p.name = "b").FirstOrDefault();
for (int i = 0; i < listInfoDetail.Count; i++)
{
    result.Add(new Info()
    {
        name = info2.name,
        age = info2.age,
        expenseN = listInfoDetail[i].expenseN,
        cost = listInfoDetail[i].cost,
        group = listInfoDetail[i].group
    });
}
return result;
```

After running this code, the result of the `result` variable is as follows:

```
result
--------------------------------------------------
num    name   age    expenseN    cost      group
1      a      20     001         10.00     x
2      a      20     001         20.00     x
3      a      20     002         20.00     x
4      b      21     001         10.00     x
5      b      21     001         20.00     x
6      b      21     002         20.00     x
```

However, that was not the result i wanted, the result i expected was like this:

```
result
--------------------------------------------------
num    name   age    expenseN    cost      group
1      a      20     001         30.00     x
2      a      20     002         20.00     x
3      b      21     001         30.00     x
4      b      21     002         20.00     x
```

After all, i want to group by and sum the `result` variable to give me the desired result. Someone please help me in this situation, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`var listInfoDetail = _infoDetailRepository.Query(p => p.group == "x").ToList();`

You have 3 entries in your `InfoDetail` table with `group == "x"`. As such `listInfoDetail` has 3 items. You do this twice so you end up with 6. Behavior is as expected.

> i want to group by and sum the result variable to give me the desired result

If you don't want to make changes to the logic, you can take your result variable and do something like this where you are grouping by `expenseN` and `name` and then summing the `cost`

```
var resultGrouped = result
            .GroupBy(x => new { x.expenseN, x.name })
            .Select(y => new Info()
            {
                name = y.Key.name,
                age = y.FirstOrDefault().age,
                expenseN = y.Key.expenseN,
                cost = y.Sum(z => z.cost),
                group = y.FirstOrDefault().group
            }).ToList();
```

But this is a very inefficient use of LINQ. You should look to improve the following things:

1. Duplicated code. You are repeating the same logic for `p.name = "a"` and `p.name = "b"`
2. Unnecessary `ToList()`. Instead of storing `listInfoDetail` and `info1` you could Join the two enumerations with a `.Join()`

Ultimately all this code could be archived with one chained LINQ statement and it would be much more efficient and shorter.

Comment: hi Slack Groverglow, i want to keep my code intact, is there a way to Group by and Sum for the last `result` variable?

Comment: yes, but you need to group by `expenseN` and `name` instead of `expenseN` and `group`

Comment: But i need to follow the logic of this `group by`, i want to keep my code intact, is there a way to Group by and Sum for the last `result` variable before it is returned?

Comment: yes, is there a way to `group by` and `sum` the last `result` variable before it is returned?

Answer (score 1):

Following code will be helpful for you to simplify the existing code and also help you to get the desired result.

```
var result = from p in InfoDetails
             where p.groups == "x"
             group p by new { p.expenseN } into g
             from c in Info
             orderby c.name, g.FirstOrDefault().expenseN
             select new
             {
               name = c.name,
               age = c.age,
               expenseN = g.FirstOrDefault().expenseN,
               cost = g.Sum(x=>x.cost),
               groups = g.FirstOrDefault().groups
             };
```

or

```
var result = InfoDetails.Where(x=>x.groups=="x").GroupBy(x=>x.expenseN).SelectMany(t1 => Info.Select(t2 => new {  
              name = t2.name,
              age = t2.age,
              expenseN = t1.FirstOrDefault().expenseN,
              cost = t1.Sum(x=>x.cost),
              groups = t1.FirstOrDefault().groups
              })).OrderBy(x=>x.name).ThenBy(x=>x.expenseN);
```